# How to install make from USB on lubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lubuntu

I have a fresh lubuntu 16.04.03 install from an USB drive. Unfortunately I am unable to install the wlan usb dongle as the make command is not available. The drivers I have but as far as I understand, I need to compile them first. Now, I do have the USB pluged in from where I successfully installed lubunut, I also have the ISO available mounted under /mnt/usb but I somehow can not "apt-get install build essentials". Unfortunately no ethernet cable at hand, just wifi.

How can I install either the wlan dongle or make on this fresh system?

Comment: It's `build-essential` (one-word).  I'd suggest using a machine that has internet capability, downloading the .deb file (`wget` or your favorite browser from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/build-essential) for your machine & saving/copying the .deb file to a usb-thumb-drive, putting the thumb-drive in your machine & installing it (`dpkg -i ...`).  It will allow you to install it on your target machine.

Comment: I tried exactly that, but there is a lot not installed like depending gcc, g++ etc. I tried to do the same thing with gcc but ended up in a long line of dependencies.

Comment: yeah I was l just wondering that ... you'll need them too..   the site I added to the prior comment lists dpkg-dev, g++, gcc, libc6-dev|libc-dev, make. Whatever you're missing will also need to be grabbed sorry.

Comment: OK, solved it by grabbing a switch and a long ethernet cable. Thank you for your help.